# How to get data after "response.data" of API

Tags: javascript

I don't know what the right code is to get all the data of the API after `response.data`. I use the API by ethermine.
Here's my code:

```
global.etherminepool = `https://api.ethermine.org/poolStats`;
axios.get(etherminepool)
.then(function(response) {
  // handle success
  
  console.log(response.data); // I tried "response.data.price.eur". Do I have to use () or []?

})
.catch(function (error) {
  // handle error
  console.log(error);
})
.then(function () {
  // always executed
});
```

When I tried `response.data.price.eur` the error is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'eur' of undefined`. Also `response.data.price` didn't work.
The response of `response.data` is:

```
{
  status: 'OK',
  data: {
    topMiners: [],       
    minedBlocks: [       
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
    poolStats: {
      hashRate: 180365172843161.53,
      miners: 320965,
      workers: 980198,
      blocksPerHour: 68.92
    },
    price: {
      time: '2021-10-10T10:09:56.000Z',
      usd: 3580.5,
      btc: 0.0650543794,
      eur: 3094.580078125,
      cny: 23070,
      rub: 257127
    },
    estimates: {
      time: '2021-10-10T10:09:56.000Z',
      blockReward: 2.1481,
      hashrate: 695958780441595,
      blockTime: 13.5318,
      gasPrice: 59.0492384812
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just _look_ at what logging `response.data` shows you - that object itself has a `data` property, along with `status`. It _doesn't_ have a `price` property.

Comment: Hello, can you give me an example how I can get "response.data.price.eur", thanks

Comment: You can't, because (as the error and what you've logged already tell you) _that doesn't exist_. You need to access the properties the object _actually has_.

Comment: Please add JSON.stringify and try

Comment: JSON.Stringify and try

Comment: @rnr that makes no sense as a suggestion, how does converting the object back to a string help with accessing the appropriate data?

Comment: So I can use JSON.stringify, but I don't know the correct way to get the value of "eur" in the price section

Comment: if response.data looks like the above, accessing the price in eur should work like this: response.data.data.price.eur. You have a data property in your response.data object. That is the one you need to access.

Comment: when you console.log is it `response.data.status` or `response.status` that returns the value "OK"?

Comment: As  @J_K sayed it is correct to use "response.data.data.price.eur". I will mark this as solution!

Comment: @Julian then this is a typo error then?

Comment: @evolutionxbox certainly "resolved in a way less likely to help future readers", anyway.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

As @J_K wrote the correct way was "response.data.data.price.eur"